# URL extension hiding : rewrite vs redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have read lots of question and answers but i cant decide which one is better or how to use a combination of these ways of extension hiding.
**what i want** is to have a url rewriting like **stackoverflow**! so what else should i do to have these rules:

```
url: example.com/file.anyEXT...  show content of => 404
url: example.com/unknown-Cat...  show content of => 404

url: example.com/cat1            show content of => example.com/cat1/index.php
url: example.com/cat1/index.php  show content of => 404
url: example.com/cat1/any...any  show content of => 404
url: example.com/cat1/11/title   show content of => example.com/cat1/single.php  (post id 11)
```

but my htaccess files just do like these:

```
url: example.com/file.anyEXT     
     show content of => example.com/index.php  (should show 404)

url: example.com/unknown-Cat
     show content of => example.com/index.php  (should show 404)

url: example.com/unknown-Cat/
    show broken content of => index.php => cant load css and js => (should show 404)

url: example.com/file.anyEXT/
     show broken content of => index.php => cant load css and js => (should show 404)

url: example.com/cat1 
     show content of => example.com/cat1/index.php (works fine!)

url: example.com/cat1/index.php
     show content of => example.com/cat1/index.php (should show 404)

url: example.com/cat1/any...any
     show content of => 404  (works fine!)

url: example.com/cat1/11/title
     show content of => example.com/cat1/single.php  (post id 11) (works fine!)
```

---

**What i have**

```
mydomain-|
         |
         |
         |__cat1-|__.htaccess  // cat1 htaccess
         |       |__index.php
         |       |__single.php
         |
         |__cat2-|__.htaccess // cat2 htaccess
                 |       |__index.php
                 |       |__single.php
                ...
                 |__.htaccess  // root htaccess
                 |__index.php  // home-page
```

**my htaccess based on most suggested way:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<files ".htaccess">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>    
Options All -Indexes

# Redirect from www.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

It is what i used in my root folder and in all my sub-folders i have two files `index.php` and `single.php`  and i have .htaccess like this in every sub folders:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cat1/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(.+?)/?$ single.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

**`DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<files ".htaccess">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>    
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect from www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,NE,R=301]

# 404 for index.php in URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

</IfModule>
```

**`/cat1/.htaccess`:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cat1/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,R=404]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ single.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: THanks alot. it works fine now except the first one. i want `example.com/file.anyEXT` to show content of => 404 however it works fine for any `/file.anyEXT` but not for `/index.php`. I want `example.com/index.php` to show 404.

Comment: ok check updated code. It will show 404 for `example.com/index.php` now.

Comment: nop! `example.com/index.php` => changes its url to `example.com`  and also something like `example.com/index.phpjj` shows 500 not 404

Comment: oops I got 500 in a new brower and here the log: a  Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error...

Comment: Internal redirect means you still have some internal rewrite rule which is NOT in my answer. You can see I don't have any internal rewrite rule in my `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` now. You have to use these 2 .htaccess exactly as shown.

Comment: now i need to add pagination to index.php inside each cat directory. but this rewrite me trough single.php :|. do you want me to update my question or ask this in a new question?

Comment: I suggest a new question since that requirement is little different from this question. I will try to answer if I can.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if mod_rewrite is even capable of what you want to do. But I guess that what you really want is bootstrapping. And this is what I guess what stackoverflow.com is also using. Like the most modern web applications

This means all request are going through a single PHP script like index.php.

So you will give the path of the request to your index.php file and it process the request and load the page requested.

Here is an explaination how it can work with PHP: http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/php-bootstrapping-crash-course/146

If you use a Framework like Zend Framework, there is properly already a bootstrapping integrated.