# rewrite and pagination interaction

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination

I am using rewrite role from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289388/url-extension-hiding-rewrite-vs-redirect) to switch between `index.php` and `single.php`. Now I want to have pagination in my index.php inside each category.
for example if i want to show

```
www.example.com/cat1/page=2 => www.example.com/cat1/index.php?page=2
```

this will go to

```
www.example.com/cat1/page=2  =>www.example.com/cat1/single.php?page=2
```

How can i fix this interaction?
From that question i have this roles:

---

```
mydomain-|
         |
         |
         |__cat1-|__.htaccess  // cat1 htaccess
         |       |__index.php
         |       |__single.php
         |
         |__cat2-|__.htaccess // cat2 htaccess
                 |       |__index.php
                 |       |__single.php
                ...
                 |__.htaccess  // root htaccess
                 |__index.php  // home-page
```

`DocumentRoot/.htaccess:`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<files ".htaccess">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>    
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect from www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,NE,R=301]

# 404 for index.php in URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

</IfModule>
```

`/cat1/.htaccess:`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cat1/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,R=404]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ single.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `/cat1/.htaccess` to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cat1/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,R=404]

RewriteRule ^(page=\d+)/?$ index.php?$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ single.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```